# React give animation only to clicked element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I wish to add spinner animation after clicking on button, when get response, spinner is supposed to disappear. So far works fine but the problem is that I render list with many elements and every element has own delete button, while clicking on one, animation is added to all elements of the list. I wish it to appear only once, next to this particular clicked element of the list.

```
 const displayCertificateList = (
  classes,
  mainStatus,
  handleDeleteSingleCertificate,
  animateDelete 
) => {
    return mainStatus.map((el, i) => {
      return (
        <div className={classes.certificatesListContainer} style={{border:'none'}}>
          <List key={i} style={{padding: '10px'}}>
            <ListItem style={{ padding: "0 0 0 20px" }}>
              <ListItemText
                className={classes.certificatesList}
                primary={
                  <Typography type="body2" style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }} className={classes.certificatesListFont}>
                    Valid until:
                  </Typography>
                }
                secondary={
                  <Typography
                    type="body2"
                    className={classNames(
                      classes.certificatesListSecondArgument,
                      classes.certificatesListFont,
                      el.expiresIn > 90 ? classes.green : classes.red
                    )}
                  >
                    {el.validUntil.slice(0,9)} ({el.expiresIn} days)
                  </Typography>
                }
              />
            </ListItem>
          </List>
          <div className={classes.certificatesBtn}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              size="small"
              color="secondary"
              className={classes.button}
              onClick={() => {
                if (
                  window.confirm(
                    `Are you really sure?
                  )
                )
                  handleDeleteSingleCertificate(el, i);
              }}
            >
              <DeleteIcon className={classes.leftIcon} />
              Delete
            </Button>
            <div style={{left: '-50%',top: '30%'}} className={classNames(animateDelete ? classes.spinner : null)}></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h6">
          The applet is not innitialized, please initialize it first
        </Typography>
      </div>
    );
};
```

And in parent component:

```
 handleDeleteSingleCertificate = (el, i) => {
    this.setState({animatingDelete: true})

    this.make_call(
      this.state.selected, 
      (res) => {
        console.log(res)
        this.setState({animatingDelete: false})
      }
    )
  }
```

And pass it like this:

```
        {this.state.view === 'certificates' && this.state.certificates && displayCertificates(classes, fakeData, this.handleDeleteSingleCertificate,  this.state.animatingDelete)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to make `displayCertificateList` function component to stateful component and store the `animatingDelete` in it - `cause it is the state of that particular item in deed.

```js
class ListItem extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isDeleting: false
  }

  handleDelete = () => {
    const { onDelete, id } = this.props;
    onDelete(id);
    this.setState({
      isDeleting: true
    })
  }
  
  render(){
    const { isDeleting } = this.state;
    return (
      <li>
        <button onClick={this.handleDelete}>Delete {isDeleting && '(spinner)'}</button>
      </li>
    )
  }
}

class List extends React.Component {
  state = {
    listItems: [
      {id: 1},
      {id: 2}
    ]
  }
  
  handleDelete = id => {
      console.log('delete ' + id);
      // do the async operation here and remove the item from state
  }
  
  render(){
    const { listItems } = this.state;
    return (
      <ul>
        {listItems.map(({id}) => (
          <ListItem id={id} key={id} onDelete={this.handleDelete} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: hey thanks for message, but even if it is stateful component, how to control to give animation to this particular element of the list? As I don't have problem to pass data through components, issue is how to make it unable to show on all elements at once, and show only on clicked one

Comment: Hello, I have implemented a skeleton of my imagination, please, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's better to use count instead of `animatingDelete` to mark. You can plus 1 when click on the delete button and then when it's done minus 1. when count equals to 0,  hide spining otherwise show it.

Comment: hmm but I don't understand what would it change? I mean animation already appears on click and disappear when get response. Problem is that I render list with many element and this spinner appears next to every button at once after clicking on any. And I want it to appear only next to clicked button